# Deleting objects in c++;

Tags: c++, delete-operator

In C you have to free the memory that has been allocated by the program. Does the same go for objects in C++?

```
class Common
{
    //some function declarations
}

void example()  
{
    Common obj;
    //do stuff with obj
    delete obj;
}
```

How important is delete obj; here if i asume the function example() will be called once only?

Comment: You do not, actually you **should not** `delete` anything on the stack. That is only if you `new` the object. The variable's memory will be freed as soon as the variable falls out of scope, at the end of your `example` function in this case.

Comment: Your first sentence is not entirely correct.

Comment: This applies only to dynamically allocated memory.

Answer (score 1):

You have not to `delete` a local object of a function that is allocated on the stack. You have to delete objects that were allocated using the operator `new`.

Moreover, the `delete` operator is applied to **pointers**. Your code snippet will not compile.